# how to fetch all data from database using one to many relation hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two table Parent table is Credit in that table only one row of data is there and another one is child table Debit that contains multiple row of data. how to fetch data from two table which has to match id of parent class and child class and no duplicate is shown from parent class.

I have try with (from Credit,debit) but that can display with duplicate and not properly data is shown based on id.

```
package com.rojmat.entity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Entity
@Table(name="credit")
public class Credit extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long cid;
    @Column @Order
    private long openingbalance;
    @Column
    private Date date;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long drawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long todaybusiness;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="credit_debit", 
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="c_id"), 
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="d_id"))
    /*@JoinColumn(name="cid", referencedColumnName="cid")*/
    private List<Debit> debits = new ArrayList<Debit>(Arrays.asList());
    public Credit() {

    }
    public Credit(long cid, long openingbalance, Date date, long debittotal, long drawertotal,
            long debittotalplusdrawertotal, long todaybusiness, List<Debit> debits) {
        super();
        this.cid = cid;
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
        this.date = date;
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    public long getCid() {
        return cid;
    }
    public void setCid(long cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }
    public long getOpeningbalance() {
        return openingbalance;
    }
    public void setOpeningbalance(long openingbalance) {
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
    }   
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public long getDebittotal() {
        return debittotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotal(long debittotal) {
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
    }
    public long getDrawertotal() {
        return drawertotal;
    }
    public void setDrawertotal(long drawertotal) {
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
    }
    public long getDebittotalplusdrawertotal() {
        return debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(long debittotalplusdrawertotal) {
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public long getTodaybusiness() {
        return todaybusiness;
    }
    public void setTodaybusiness(long todaybusiness) {
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
    }
    public List<Debit> getDebit() { 
        return debits;
    }   
    public void setDebit(List<Debit> debit) {   
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    /*@Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Credit [cid=" + cid + ", openingbalance =" + openingbalance + ", date=" + date + ", debittotal= " + debittotal + ", debittotalplusdrawertotal=" + debittotalplusdrawertotal + ", todaybusiness=" + todaybusiness + "]";
    }*/
}
```

```
package com.rojmat.entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="debit")
public class Debit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long did;
    @Column
    private String amount;
    @Column
    private String description; 

    public Debit() {

    }
    public Debit(String amount, String description) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public long getDid() {
        return did;
    }
    public void setDid(long did) {
        this.did = did;
    }
    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Debit [did=" + did + ", amount =" + amount + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
}
```

1.CreditDaoImpl.java

```
package com.rojmat.daoImpl;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.rojmat.dao.CreditDao;
import com.rojmat.entity.Credit;

@Repository
public class CreditDaoImpl implements CreditDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Override
    public void addCreditDebit(Credit credit) {
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(credit);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteCreditDebit(int cid) {
        /*Credit credit = (Credit)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Credit as c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.Debit where c.cid="+cid).uniqueResult();
        List<Debit> debits = credit.getDebit();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(credit);
        debits.forEach((debit) -> {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(debit);
        });*/
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Credit> getAllCreditDebit() {
        List<Credit> credit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Credit,Debit").list();
        return credit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this example:** you put "distinct" before the property you do not want to be duplicated

```
//SQL query

select distinct credit.idCredit as idCredit from Credit credit Left Join Debit debit on credit.idCredit= debit.idCredit

//HQL query 

@Entity(name = "Credit")
@Table(name = "Credit")
public class Credit{


    //if you put @Id  --> HQL Query "select credit from Credit credit"
    @Column(name = "idCredit")
    private Long idCredit;

    @Column(name = "label")
    private String label;

    @OneToMany 
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "idCredit" ,referencedColumnName = "idCredit")})
    List<Debit> debits;

  ...
}
public class Debit{
    ....


    @Column(name = "idCredit")
    private Long idCredit;
    ...
}

    Query query = getSession().createQuery("select distinct credit.idCredit as idCredit, credit.label as label, credit.debits as debits from Credit credit   ");
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Credit.class));
    return query.list();
```

```
package com.rojmat.entity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Entity
@Table(name="credit")
public class Credit extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long cid;
    @Column @Order
    private long openingbalance;
    @Column
    private Date date;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long drawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long todaybusiness;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="credit_debit", 
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="c_id"), 
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="d_id"))
    /*@JoinColumn(name="cid", referencedColumnName="cid")*/
    private List<Debit> debits = new ArrayList<Debit>(Arrays.asList());
    public Credit() {

    }
    public Credit(long cid, long openingbalance, Date date, long debittotal, long drawertotal,
            long debittotalplusdrawertotal, long todaybusiness, List<Debit> debits) {
        super();
        this.cid = cid;
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
        this.date = date;
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    public long getCid() {
        return cid;
    }
    public void setCid(long cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }
    public long getOpeningbalance() {
        return openingbalance;
    }
    public void setOpeningbalance(long openingbalance) {
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
    }   
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public long getDebittotal() {
        return debittotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotal(long debittotal) {
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
    }
    public long getDrawertotal() {
        return drawertotal;
    }
    public void setDrawertotal(long drawertotal) {
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
    }
    public long getDebittotalplusdrawertotal() {
        return debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(long debittotalplusdrawertotal) {
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public long getTodaybusiness() {
        return todaybusiness;
    }
    public void setTodaybusiness(long todaybusiness) {
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
    }
    public List<Debit> getDebit() { 
        return debits;
    }   
    public void setDebit(List<Debit> debit) {   
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    /*@Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Credit [cid=" + cid + ", openingbalance =" + openingbalance + ", date=" + date + ", debittotal= " + debittotal + ", debittotalplusdrawertotal=" + debittotalplusdrawertotal + ", todaybusiness=" + todaybusiness + "]";
    }*/
}
```

```
package com.rojmat.entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="debit")
public class Debit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long did;
    @Column
    private String amount;
    @Column
    private String description; 

    public Debit() {

    }
    public Debit(String amount, String description) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public long getDid() {
        return did;
    }
    public void setDid(long did) {
        this.did = did;
    }
    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    /*@Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Debit [did=" + did + ", amount =" + amount + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }*/
}
```

Comment: sql query is correct but that will only id is shown not display all data

Comment: in sql query you want to add all properties : select distinct credit.idCredit as idCredit, label as label,......,debit.id as id, debit.propertyName as ... from Credit credit Left Join Debit debit on credit.idCredit= debit.idCredit

Comment: as per your given answer that is correct. but from debit table two field is there and that two field have multiple rows when i try to fire this query then only single record is display from Debit table

Comment: I have pasted in your comment

Comment: public List<Credit> getAllCreditDebit() {
        List<Credit> credit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct credit.cid as cid,credit.openingbalance as openingbalance,credit.date as date,credit.debittotal as debittotal,credit.drawertotal as drawertotal,credit.debittotalplusdrawertotal as debittotalplusdrawertotal,credit.todaybusiness as todaybusiness from Credit credit").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Credit.class));
        return credit.list;
    }

Comment: Debit class of data is automatically retrieve ? you cannot write query for Debit class

Comment: Debit is mapped in Credit class with OneToMany "debits" and hibernate will retrive debit data automatically and complete all "Debit" alias via "setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Credit.class))".

Comment: i changed hql use this :  

  public List<Credit> getAllCreditDebit() {
        List<Credit> credit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct credit.cid as cid,credit.openingbalance as openingbalance,credit.date as date,credit.debittotal as debittotal,credit.drawertotal as drawertotal,credit.debittotalplusdrawertotal as debittotalplusdrawertotal,credit.todaybusiness as todaybusiness,credit.debits as debits  from Credit credit")
  .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Credit.class))
  .list();
        return credit;
    }